# Solve problem regarding this LSD Radix sort

Tags: algorithm, radix-sort

A billion integers in the range 0....2^32-1 will be sorted by LSD radix sort. How much faster is this done using radix 0....2^8-1 rather than 0....2^4-1?
I tried using the k, n, d, range technique, and tried finding time using formula
`Q(d(n+k))`. where `Q = time`.

Comment: The time required by radix sort is directly proportional to the number of radixes required. Cut the size of the radix in half, and the number of passes of the algorithm doubles.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What is your idea about it ?

Comment: @m.raynal
For A    For B
(28-1)   (24-1)
  
k = 2 (binary)  k = 2 (binary)
n = 1B (Billion)  n = 1B (Billion)
d = 254 (28-1)  d = 15 (28-1)
range = 109  range = 109 
  
Q(d(n+k))
A is approx.. 16 times faster than B

Comment: @m.raynal, please copy that to notepad too see the numbers clearly. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @sujanpandey Do not put updates in comments. Instead, edit your question and add new information and clarifications there. As you can see, formatting capabilities in comments is minimal.